# Messy function pointer interpretation

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

I happen to come across the following function pointer.

```
char (*(*x())[])();
```

It looks like an array of function pointer in the following format, but I can't see what f -> (*x()) means. How to interpret this messy function pointer?

```
char (*f[])();
```

### ADDED

With John Bode's help, I make an example as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char foo()    { return 'a'; }
char bar()    { return 'b'; }
char blurga() { return 'c'; }
char bletch() { return 'd'; }

char (*gfunclist[])() = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};

char (*(*x())[])()
{
  static char (*funclist[4])() = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};
  return &funclist;
}

int main() 
{
  printf("%c\n",gfunclist[0]());

  char (*(*fs)[4])();
  fs = x();
  printf("%c\n",(*fs)[1]()); 
}
```

I could get the expected result.

```
smcho@prosseek temp2> ./a.out 
a
b
```

And, you can find a better implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107934/messy-function-pointer-how-to-remove-the-warning).

Comment: Kernighan and Ritchie ought to be prosecuted for allowing syntax like this ;)

Comment: What are you talking about?  That code is *perfectly* transparent and understandable. :p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My general procedure is to find the leftmost identifier in the declaration, and then work my way out, remembering that `[]` and `()` bind before `*` (i.e., `*f()` is normally parsed as `*(f())` and `*a[]` is normally parsed as `*(a[])`).

So,

```
          x           -- x
          x()         -- is a function
         *x()         -- returning a pointer
        (*x())[]      -- to an array
       *(*x())[]      -- of pointers
      (*(*x())[])()   -- to functions
 char (*(*x())[])();  -- returning char
```

What would such a beast look like in practice?

```
char foo()    { return 'a'; }
char bar()    { return 'b'; }
char blurga() { return 'c'; }
char bletch() { return 'd'; }

/**  
 *           funclist           -- funclist
 *           funclist[]         -- is an array
 *          *funclist[]         -- of pointers
 *         (*funclist[])()      -- to functions
 *    char (*funclist[])()      -- returning char
 */    
char (*funclist[])() = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};
```

The expression `&funclist` will return a pointer to the array, so

```
char (*(*x())[])()
{
  return &funclist;
}
```

Comment: +1 for "teaching to fish" (your detailed explanation), as opposed to handing the original asker a basket of fish ("go to cdecl.org")

Answer (score 6):

```
char (*(*x())[])();
```

`x is a  function returning pointer to array of pointer to function returning char`

```
char (*f[])();
```

In this case `f is an array of pointer to function returning char`

Using the [**right-left rule**](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html) would be beneficial.

Comment: Could you please, for clarity and understandability, tell us how you decipher that so quickly? With bold or italics, step by step? Thanks :)

Comment: @Benoit : Check out the link that I have given in my post.

Answer (score 5):

```
cdecl> explain char (*(*x())[])();
declare x as function returning pointer to array of pointer to function returning char
```

Answer (score 3):

A few typedefs make it clearer:

```
typedef char (*charfunc_t)();
```

This defines `charfunc_t` to be a pointer to a function without arguments that returns `char`.

```
typedef charfunc_t funcarr_t[];
```

`funcarr_t` is an array of such function pointers.

`x` is a function returning a pointer to such an array and it can now be declared like this:

```
funcarr_t* x();
```

Answer (score 2):

Visit this site to help you understand c declarations ([cdecl.org](http://www.cdecl.org)), if you type the above in, it will tell you this

> declare x as function returning pointer to array of pointer to function returning char