# Messy function pointer : how to remove the warning?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

As I asked and answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106362/messy-function-pointer-interpretation). I have the following example code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char foo()    { return 'a'; }
char bar()    { return 'b'; }
char blurga() { return 'c'; }
char bletch() { return 'd'; }

char (*gfunclist[])() = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};

char (*(*x())[])()
{
  static char (*funclist[4])() = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};
  return funclist;
}

int main() 
{
  printf("%c\n",gfunclist[0]());

  char (**fs)();
  fs = x();
  printf("%c\n",fs[1]()); 
}
```

My questions are

- Why the

  ```
  return funclist (with "warning: return from incompatible pointer type")
  ```

  and

  ```
  return &funclist
  ```

  both works?
- I get warning at the line 21 (fs = x();) of

  ```
  warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
  ```

  . How to remove this warning?

### ADDED

With AndreyT's help. I could get the following code that doesn't have the warnings.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char foo()    { return 'a'; }
char bar()    { return 'b'; }
char blurga() { return 'c'; }
char bletch() { return 'd'; }

char (*gfunclist[])() = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};

char (*(*x())[])()
{
  static char (*funclist[4])() = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};
  return &funclist;
}

int main() 
{
  printf("%c\n",gfunclist[0]());

  char (*(*fs)[4])();
  fs = x();
  printf("%c\n",(*fs)[1]()); 
}
```

And this is less messy code with the help from peoro.

```
typedef char (*funptr)();

funptr gfunclist[] = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};

funptr* x()
{
  static funptr funclist[4] = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};
  return funclist;
}

int main() 
{
  printf("%c\n",gfunclist[0]());

  funptr *fs;
  fs = x();
  printf("%c\n",fs[1]()); 
}
```

Comment: That was some weird code. I can't see the problem though :-/

Comment: `typedef`'s are your friends. Use them: `typedef char (*get_ch_fn)();` and then you can easily state things in terms of that: `get_ch_fn g_func_list[] = { foo, bar, ... }`, `get_ch_fn* x() { ...`

Comment: Please make **typedefs**, you have three level of indirection ( two * and one [] ), so please don't be proud enough to pretend you can understand what you do, a few men can. This code is ugly and unreadable. Make a typedef for each level of indirection, and then you will understand a little what you are doing.

Comment: Gah, I didn't mean for anyone to actually *use* that code; it was just a stupid example to illustrate the relationships between the various types (that's the primary reason it doesn't use typedefs).  Had I known anyone was going to actually try to compile and run it, I would have written it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to decide whether you are using C or C++. These languages are significantly different in their treatment of the situations like yours.

In C++ a "pointer to an `[]` array" (i.e an array of unspecificed size) is a completely different type from a "pointer to an [N] array" (i.e. an array of specified size). This immediately means that your code has no chance to compile as C++ code. It is not a "warning", it is an error. If you want your code to compile as C++, you need to specfiy the exact array size in the function return type

```
char (*(*x())[4])() // <- see the explicit 4 here?
{
  static char (*funclist[4])() = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};
  return &funclist;
}
```

And, of course, you have to return `&funclist`, since you are declaring your function as returning a *pointer to an array*.

In `main` declaring the receiving pointer as `char (**fs)()` makes no sense whatsoever. The function is returning a *pointer to an array*, not a *pointer to a pointer*. You need to declare your `fs` as

```
char (*(*fs)[4])(); // <- pointer to an array
```

i.e. as having *pointer-to-array* type (note the similarity to the function declaration). And in order to call the function through such a pointer you have to do

```
printf("%c\n", (*fs)[1]());
```

In C language the explicit array size in the pointer-to-array declarations can be omitted, since in C "pointer to an [] array" type is compatible with "pointer to an [N] array" type, but the other points still stand. However, even in C it might make more sense to specify that size explicitly.

---

Alternatively, you can stop using pointer-to-array type and instead use *pointer-to-pointer* type. In that case your function should be defined as follows

```
char (**x())()
{
  static char (*funclist[4])() = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};
  return funclist; // <- no `&` here
}
```

and in `main` you'll work with it as follows

```
char (**fs)();
fs = x();
printf("%c\n", fs[1]());
```

Note, that this `main` is the same as what you had in your original post. In other words, your original code is a bizarre fusion of two different absolutely incompatible techniques. You have to decide which one you want to use and stick to it.

Comment: Hum... <code>type array[] = { /* something */ };</code> IS a valid C expression... --- Oh, you were talking about the signature of x. Sorry then.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to typedef your function pointer, otherwise it's hard to see what's happening.

```
typedef char (*funptr)();
```

Anyway, `x` returns a pointer to `char (*(*x())[])`, and `funclist` is not that thing.

Same for `fs=x();`: `char ((())[]) != char (**)();`...

If I'm not wrong there are also some errors with precedence between [] and *...

This is working fine:

```
typedef char (*funptr)();

funptr gfunclist[] = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};

funptr *x() {
  static funptr funclist[4] = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};
  return funclist;
}

funptr *fs;
fs = x();
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first question,

```
cdecl> explain char (*(*x())[])()
declare x as function returning pointer to array of pointer to function returning char
cdecl> explain static char (*funclist[4])()
declare funclist as static array 4 of pointer to function returning char
```

So the expected return type of x is a pointer to an array of pointers to functions returning char, but what you're returning is just an array of pointers to functions returning char. By adding the &, you are now in fact returning a pointer to the array of pointers to functions returning char.

For the second, again the expected return type of x is a pointer to an array of pointers to functions returning char, but we see

```
cdecl> explain char (**fs)();
declare fs as pointer to pointer to function returning char
```

What you want instead is `char (*(*fs)[])();`

```
cdecl> explain char (*(*fs)[])();
declare fs as pointer to array of pointer to function returning char
```

Comment: Because as I said, without the & "what you're returning is just an array of pointers to functions returning char" when you need a pointer to that whole mess.

Answer (score 1):

Choose either the extra `*` or the `[]` in the return type of `x`, not both.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `T a[] = { .. };` then `a` is declared as having type `T[N]`, but not as having type `T[]`.

So you need to put some number in the brackets.

```
char (*(*x())[sizeof(gfunclist)/sizeof(*gfunclist)])()
{
  return &gfunclist;
}
```

It will limit what you can return to a specific size. This is where C++ differs from C, which will allow you to assign a `T(*)[N]` to an `T(*)[]`. C++ has no such so-called "type compatibility" rules. If you want to get rid of the need for the `&`, you need to return the decay-type of the array. The element type of your array is `char(*)()`

```
char (**x())()
{
  static char (*funclist[4])() = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};
  return funclist;
}
```

Using an identity template you can make your declaration look much more readable

```
template<typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };
identity<char()>::type **x()
{
  static identity<char()>::type *funclist[] = {foo, bar, blurga, bletch};
  return funclist;
}
```